# Parallel OpenMP ordered for loop with break statement

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am using OpenMP to parallelize the following code：

```
int fx(){
    int x, sum;
    for(int i=0; i<10000; ++i){
        x = fx2(sum);
        if(......) break;
        sum += x;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Because that `sum` must be added in order due to the call to `fx2()`. I choose to use `ordered` clause of OpenMP while applying `schedule(dynamic)` (since the loop may not run for the entire 10000 times)：

```
int fx(){
    int x, sum;
    bool flag = true;
#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic) private(x)
{
    for(int i=0; i<10000; ++i){
        if(flag == false) continue;
        x = fx2(sum);
        if(......) flag = false;
#pragma omp ordered
        sum += x;
    }
    return sum;
}
}
```

However, it seems that the outcome is not correct, the program runs so long. Is there anything wrong with the parallelized OpenMP code?

Comment: It seems that what you are trying to calculate cannot be easily parallelized.

Comment: Take a look at the OpenMP _reduction_ clause, it was made for such computations. However, make sure that the function you call has no side effects i.e. is a pure function.